# Inserting data to mysql db with special characters

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to read a docx file, than split it into the important parts and insert them into a mysql database. The problem is that my docx file is in portuguese, so it has a lot of special characters (e.g. á, ã, â) and I'm struggling myself to solve this problem for some days already. Because when I add to the database, the special characters turn to '?'.

This is my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",
                     user="filipefr",
                     passwd="da66ro",
                     db="quiz_db",
                     charset='utf8',
                         use_unicode=True)

cursor = db.cursor()
document = docx.Document('teste.docx')
docText = '\n\n'.join([paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs])
d2 = docText.decode("utf-8")

N = len(d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n"))

query = ''
questao = {}

for i in range(0,N):
    s = d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i]
    try:
        isinstance(int(s[0:2]), int)
        questao[num_questoes] = d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i][3:len(s)]
        query = 'INSERT INTO multichoice_question (category_id, content) VALUES ("4", "' + d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i][3:len(s)] + '");'
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            db.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "error %s" %e
            db.rollback()  
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Make sure your database has the adequate setting for accepting unicode characters. I remember having the same issues a year ago and the culprit was that my database wasnt set to accept unicode characters

Comment: @Beginner my field Collation is utf8_general_ci. Is this the correct one?

Comment: @Beginner I think my db is okay, because I tried to insert a string manually with special characters, and it looks perfect for me. I think the problem is in the python code/reading the file

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? Even that can be a problem, I think python 3 and higher can handle unicode better.